# ASP.NET Core + Git - How to organise multiple projects and solutions in a git repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I'm looking for some tips/best practices about how to organize ASP.NET Core projects and solution(s) in Azure Dev Ops git repositories.

For example - I have following projects:

```
- App.Data (EF Core DB context)
- App.Api (ASP.NET Core API that access DB via App.Data)
- App.ApiClient (.Net Core Class library with Api contracts and wrapped endpoint methods)
- App.Admin (ASP.NET Core Web, could be Blazor or MVC - administration)
- App.Frontend (ASP.NET Core Web, could be Blazor or MVC - web for users)
```

References:

- App.Api needs App.Data (to use DB) and App.ApiClient (to use contract
  classes)
- App.Admin needs App.ApiClient (to use contracts and call wrapped endpoint methods)
- App.Frontend needs App.ApiClient (to use contracts and call wrapped endpoint methods)

**What are your experiences with the structure inside Git repositories? Should I have an entire solution in one repository or should I split it into multiple (and how)?**

I'm using automatic build and release pipelines in Azure Dev Ops, so I have one repository to deal with cross-referencing.

**But** I'm also thinking about the future - there is the posibillity of reusing the application for another web. In this case, I will need another "rebranded" App.Frontend, but maybe I'd like to use the same API and Admin. I don't want to fork the entire solution, because if I will fix something in the new one I have to manually transfer it to the old one.

**But** If I split the solution into multiple (Data, Api, ApiClient, Admin?) and (Frontend) than I have to publish some of the projects to Nuget to be able to reference it in Frontend web - (I think it have to be Nuget to be accessible in Azure Dev Ops build pipeline).

I think this type of VS solution is quite common, so someone already has to deal with it :-)
Thank you very much for your advice.

Comment: Consider git submodules and subtrees (subtrees are better than submodules, but subtrees aren't supported by most git GUIs I've seen (e.g. neither Visual Studio nor GitKraken support subtrees in their GUI so you'll always need to use the command-line).

Comment: Unless your API (or API client) are already “done” (as in: you can develop the whole frontend mostly without having to rely on additional changes to the API), it makes more sense to have the projects directly combined, i.e. within the same repo and ideally within the same solution. Because you will need to constantly touch the API and the API client as the frontends develop. If you later have a stable API and you need additional projects you can always split it up. And your new frontend also doesn’t necessarily need to be connected; just pack the client as a NuGet package and reference that.